# Is there any way to echo the path of a included file?

Tags: php

I want to see the path of a file included in a php file, for example

```
include("../resources/templates/front/footer.php");
```

I want to see the results like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\main\ecom\resources\templates\front
```

Is there any way to echo the included file and get the full path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) should do the trick:

```
echo realpath("../resources/templates/front/footer.php");
```